# Trying to get Twitter cursor to work with api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, pagination

I'm trying to use the cursor method in order to gather a full list of users/friends instead of the same one over and over from my user. Please help. Thanks for your time and effort :)

My code:

```
cursor = -1
followerIds = []
while cursor != 0 do
 followers_user = user.followers("user", {:cursor => cursor})

 cursor = followers_user.next_cursor
 followerIds+= followers.ids
 sleep(2)
end
```

My Response:

```
#private method `next_cursor' called for #<Twitter::Cursor:0x007fd47482a208> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the cursor directly.  It's automatic.  To get all the followers for a user, just use `each`:

```
user.followers("username").each do |twitter_user|
  # do something with twitter_user
end
```

If you just want the ids, use:

```
user.follower_ids("username").each do |id|
  # do something with twitter id
end
```

Comment: that's not true man, you get like 280..and you'll get the same ones over and over unless you know how to use the cursor method.  :\

Comment: That problem does not happen for me.

Comment: so when you talk to the twitter api, your user doesn't have a request time out? @infused

Comment: No timeouts.  Are you doing something very time consuming inside the each block?

Comment: not even, just tryna get a list of ids into an array @infused

Comment: unless there's some method or call that says get "all" friends @infused

Comment: That's exactly what these do.  Are you using each? It passes each twitter user into the block and automatically increments the cursor and makes the necessary requests behind the scenes.  At the end of the loop you should have consumed all the friends.